# subdomain redirect best practices

Tags: nginx, redirect, 301-redirect

I'm setting up a site served by Nginx on FreeBSD. The only content is at sub.example.net, and I'd like to 301 any requests to example.net, [www.example.net](http://www.example.net), and [www.sub.example.net](http://www.sub.example.net).

My current solution is:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.net www.example.net www.sub.example.net;
    return 301 $scheme://sub.example.net/$request_uri;
}
```

Is a wildcard redirect the more correct way to do this, or is there something better?

```
server {
   listen 80 default_server;
   server_name  _;
   return 301 $scheme://sub.example.net/$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: The first one won't redirect random bots using a random `Host:` header to the primary domain if there is another `server` block with `default_server` defined.

Comment: None of these are near the best practices in 2024. This day and age you MUST have HTTPS and SHOULD have HSTS. With these there is a best practice for this redirection, too.

Comment: @EsaJokinen I do have HTTPS and an HTTP —> HTTPS redirect, I just didn't note that in the question because it's not relevant to the topic of subdomain redirects. Additionally, the site isn't doing anything nearly sensitive enough to warrant excluding users of older devices, which is what HSTS does.

Comment: How exactly HSTS has anything to do with older devices that don't support it and, therefore, won't do anything differently? You said you have HTTP to HTTPS redirection which would "exclude users with older devices", but we would be talking about ancient devices from decades ago. Not using and enforcing HTTPS simply doesn't make any sense anymore. And yes, it is relevant because you asked about best practices. That is the best practice. On the other hand, how you do plain HTTP redirects is entirely opinion based.